# jQPlot Horizontal Bar Graph - assign names to Y Axis

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I figured it out:

---

I was not including the jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer. Once I included that, I was able to get it working.

Thanks, everyone!

---

UPDATE:

My code works in JSFiddle, so it's a CSS problem I'm having. Please disregard.

I'm trying to create a fairly simple bar chart in jQPlot. I'm expecting two horizontal bars, one on top of the other. Both are equal to 1 on the X axis. I want the Y axis to have the labels 'In Progress' for the top bar, and 'Apr 2014' for the bottom bar. I have tried numerous combinations. If I do not specify Ticks, then I see the two bars. Specifying Ticks, or using the desired labels as the Y axis data point just shows both labels overlapping with no bars. (ignore the setTimeout) Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
var data = [[1,1],[1,2]];
var ticks = ['In Progress','Mar 2014'];
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chartdiv', [data],
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            },
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        }
    });
}, 
100);
```

});

Comment: Is [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/CjLR7/) what you after sir ?

Comment: That didn't do anything in JSFiddle, but I seem to have a CSS issue.

Comment: Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/CjLR7/1/) an updated JsFiddle link given by [Batu Zet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1906094/batu-zet) previously.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the JsFiddle given by [Batu Zet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906094/batu-zet) previously adding following lines in order to label your bar chart [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/CjLR7/3/) :

```
series: [
 {
  pointLabels:{
   show:true,
   labels:['Apr 2014', 'Apr 2014']
  }
 },
 {
  pointLabels:{
   show:true,
   labels:['In Progress', 'In Progress']
  }
 }
]
```

P.S : The labels are duplicated for each serie in order to display the same label for two points in a serie.